# setTimeout() for hibernate doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, session-timeout

I am trying to get a timeout in place such that if the hibernate query takes more than certain time to return I want to end the query and throw an exception. But never does the an exception get raised, every time the query completes successfully, even when the timeout is set to 0. Here is the code block:

```
  final Query<T> query = this.currentSession()
     .createQuery(criteria);

  dateParameters.forEach(query::setParameter);
  numberParameters.forEach(query::setParameter);
  textParameters.forEach(query::setParameter);

  List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
  try {
      result = query.setTimeout(0).list();
  } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      throw new TimeoutException("Timeout!!!");
  }
  return result;
```

I have also tried using:

```
.setHint("javax.persistence.query.timeout", 1).list();

.setHint("org.hibernate.timeout", 0).list();
```

Definitely missing something here, any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The support for timeouts depends on the JDBC driver support and most JDBC drivers do no support this AFAIK. There usually are settings for global lock/query/statement timeouts though.